# KeyNotFound exception using prism regions when setMaxHeight for Window

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using Prism regions in one of my WPF applications. As soon as i set the maximum height of the window in its constructor as shown here 
`this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;` 
then the line of code 
`IRegion pageRegion = _regionManager.Regions["PageLayout"];` 
starts throwing KeyNotFound exception but when i comment out the line for setting the `MaxHeight`, everything starts working again.

Any pointers for resolving this odd behavior?

Comment: i faced almost same issue. can you write statement `IRegion pageRegion = _regionManager.Regions["PageLayout"];` two times and see what happen? write first one in try catch

Comment: Nothing happens !!! Same result on the second statement which is outside the try block.

Comment: hmm it worked for me thats why I asked you. have you tried with some hard coded value ? `this.MaxHeight = 400;`

Comment: Even a harcoded value does not work. Tried it already !!